# Some of my Templates (and other Elements) have disappeared. Where are they?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I recently cleaned up my ModX Elements so that I categorized them. I added several categories and then started moving my Templates and other Elements into them. They aren't showing up in the list anymore and I can't get to them. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that they are still there. If you check your website they are probably still loading correctly. There is a problem with the Elements list in ModX Revolution 2.1+ (so far unfixed). If you have nested categories and there is nothing in the level above, then ModX doesn't show the other categories. If you place a dummy Template in the level above, you'll see them appear for you.

**Note:** This does happen with other elements too.

Comment: Just a sidenote; this happens on my server too. Try clearing the cache or use ftp to clear all folders in core/cache/ manually. Should work.

Comment: Always a great tip. +1. Doesn't always work when in categories. Issue is still present in 2.2.4. It's been reported. I'm just a sucker for categories, so I've learned some of the ins and outs. In 2.2.4, this only happens with templates anymore (so far).